# Showing the "boundaries" of linear mapping $\mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations

From S.L Linear Algebra:

> Let $A$, $B$ be two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ forming a basis of
>   $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$  be a
>   linear map. **Show** that either $F(A)$, $F(B)$ are linearly independent,
>   or the image of $F$ has dimension $1$, or the image of $F$ is $\{O\}$.

---

I've taken following theorems from the book to try and construct the answer (proofs of theorems are omitted):

> **Theorem 3.1.** Let $F: V \rightarrow W$ be a linear map whose kernel is $\{O\}$ . If $v ,
>  ... ,v_n$ are linearly independent elements of $V$, then $F(v_1), ...
>  ,F(v_n)$ are linearly independent elements of $W$.
>
> ---
>
> **Theorem 3.2.** Let $V$ be a vector space. Let $L: V \rightarrow W$ be a linear map of $V$ into another space $W$. Let $n$ be the
>   dimension of $V$, $q$ the dimension of the kernel of $L$, and $s$ the
>   dimension of the image of $L$. Then $n = q + s$. In other words,
>
> $$dim \, V=dim\, Ker \, L + dim\, Im \, L$$

---

This is how far I got:

> **My Progress:** First, we consider that, if $s=dim \, Im \, F$ and $q=dim \, Ker \, F$, then $dim \, V=s+q$
>   (see **Theorem 3.2**). Then, For $F(A)$, $F(B)$ to be linearly independent, kernel
>   must be trivial (see **Theorem 3.1**), and hence a linear map must be injective.
>   If linear map is **not injective**, mapping is only **surjective** and hence we can conclude that $n \in \{0, 1\} < 2$ in a linear mapping $\mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$.
>
> Considering that $n=s+q$ ($dim \, V=dim \, Im \, F + dim \, Ker \, F$) and that $n \in \{0, 1\} < 2$, either both kernel and image are
>   $0$-dimensional, **or** only one of them has a dimension of $1$ (and the other one is zero-dimensional).
>
> Also, using **Theorem 3.2**, we can derive following equations for dimensions of vector space, image under $F$ and kernel under $F$ respectively:
>    $$\textrm{(1)} \, dim \, V= dim \, Ker \, F + dim \, Im \, F$$ 
>    $$\textrm{(2)} \, dim \, Im \, F = dim \, V - dim \, Ker \, F$$
>    $$\textrm{(3)} \, dim \, Ker \, F = dim \, V - dim \, Im \, F$$
>   where $dim \, V \in \{0, 1\}$. (dimension of vector space is either $1$ or $0$)
>
> ---
>
> **In conclusion:**
>
> If $dim \, V = 0$, both kernel and image are nildimensional (0 dimensional) scalars.
>
> If dimension of vector space is not $0$ and if $dim \, V = 1$, then $(dim \, Im \,F = 1 \land dim \, Ker \,F = 0) \,  \lor \, (dim \, Ker \,F = 1 \land dim \, Im \,F = 0$). (either dimension of the image of $F$ 
>    is $1$ and dimension of kernel is $0$, or vice versa).
>
> But this is still insufficient information to prove the assertion given above.

How can I use the information above to show that the image must either have dimension of $1$ or else the kernel must be trivial ($/{0/}$)?

It seems like, in this particular case, if kernel has dimension $1$ then it must be trivial. Is there any correlation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to clarify what exactly your question is asking. Your question asks us to consider a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, for some integer $n$. I believe the question does not ask you to consider different values of $n$, but instead concerns how a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to some vector space might behave.

Rephrasing, let $W$ be any vector space, and let $F : \mathbb{R}^2 \to W$ be a linear map. We would then like to show that either $F(A), F(B)$ are linearly independent, the image of $F$ is of dimension $1$, or $F$ is the zero map.

You are right to want to make extensive use of Theorem 3.2. It is a rather useful result, so I shall do the same. Since $F$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, $F$ is going to play the role of $L$, $\mathbb{R}^2$ will be $V$, and $\mathbb{R}^n$ will be $W$ in the theorem. The theorem then says that 
$$\dim V = \dim \ker L + \dim \text{im } L.$$
In our case, this means that 
\begin{align}
 \dim \mathbb{R}^2 &= \dim \ker F + \dim \text{im } F\\
\implies 2 &= \dim \ker F + \dim \text{im } F \text{ (The dimension of $\mathbb{R}^2 = 2$)}.
\end{align}
So no matter how $F$ acts on $A$ and $B$, it is always true that the sum of the dimension of its kernel and the dimension of its image will be $2$. We know that the dimension of a vector space must be an integer and cannot be negative, so this restricts our list of possible choices for $\dim \ker F$. Then $\dim \ker F = 0, 1, $ or $2$ (if $2$ is the sum of two positive numbers, what other choices do we have?).

Now we just see what happens to our linear map in each case. If $\dim \ker F = 0$, then what does $F$ look like? As you mentioned before, if $\ker F = \{0\}$, then $F(A), F(B)$ are linearly independent by Theorem 3.1 (what is the dimension of the image in this case?).

If you answered the question above, then you will see that if $\dim \ker F = 1$, it follows that $\dim \text{im } F = 1$ as well (use one of your formulas from (1) to (3)).

Lastly, we have the case where $\dim \ker F = 2$. Presumably, we know that $\ker F$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and since $\dim \ker F = 2$, it follows that $\ker F = \mathbb{R}^2$. What does this say about $\text{im } F$? (Take a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and see what $F$ does to it, also use one of your formulas from (1) to (3) like before).

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! Seems like I've misunderstood Theorem 3.2 and forgot that it is giving us dimension of $V$ and not $W$. On your last paragraph, I'm assuming that image is nildimensional, though I'm not certain, what does it exactly show? Thank you again.

Comment: @ShellRox Well if we use formula (2), we see that $\dim \text{im } F = \dim V - \dim \ker F$. In this case we assumed $\dim \ker F = 2$, so as you said the image would be nildimensional (I'm assuming that means of dimension $0$). But what I was alluding to is that if $\ker F = V$ then $F$ sends everything in its domain to $0$. That is, it's the zero map.

Comment: Well. that explains everything. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you write $n=1$ or $n=0$. If I understood your notation correctly, then $n$ is the dimension of a given space - hence not a variable. However, the integers $s,q$ are not fixed in your setting as you should prove something exactly about these. I would also recommend to think about examples of spaces that has dimension zero. If need be, I can of course expand, but imho this might be a good first push for you to revisit your attempt.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I may have had few mistakes in the notations, but what I mentioned was that $dim \, V= dim \, Im F + dim \, Ker F$. This was proved in the textbook by using linear transformation properties on the basis of subspaces (I can add it to answer, if necessary). As for nildimensional space, a point is all I can visualize.

Comment: Well but not any point though, in fact there is only one zero-dimensional subspace in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Also notice that the formula of the dimensions is indeed the key, but the left-hand side is simply fixed since $V$ is given, whereas your task is to show something about the linear mapping $F$ that appears on the right-hand side.

Comment: Apologies if I'm misunderstanding the comment. I've mentioned that for mapping $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ to be injective, kernel must be trivial and vice versa. Otherwise the mapping should be surjective and $n$ less than $2$. Is this a correct path? If so, then I'm not certainly sure how can i precisely find dimension of kernel or the image, all I know is that $n=q+s$ where $n  > 2$. I'm not aware of further steps unfortunately.